# HGST HDD am i to dumb to install a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I bought a Deskstar 6TB HDD from HGST and i returned it because it could not be identified by either of my computers and also in made strange sounds. Today i recieved my replacement and it made the same sound upon plugging it in. 
I tried the hdd in all my computers. A HP Gen 8 Microserver with a IBM 1050 HBA, an gaming pc with a brand new board and a USB bridge. Neither worked. The "sound" it makes also appears when i just plug in power.

I made a video of the sound.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XIH0UXj22Jv7ZqKcGgILMoLaZ-eqD7RZ

Comment: check the SMART stats, format the disk, check SMART again. run `chkdsk -r` and check your stats again. if your SMART stats are not stellar after having reviewed every sector on the disk, then return it.

Comment: The HDD wont even be recognized. DMESG only gives me:                                        [13388.382729] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read

Comment: well, then you can only run the initial check. the manufacturer will respond better if you can tell them exactly whats wrong, (high raw read error rate, reallocated or pending sectors, etc).

Comment: Do you connect them internally/SATA or via USB ?

Comment: The first HDD i installed into the microserver first the replacement i tried on the USB bridge first.

Answer (score 1):

Your drive (drives) are stuffed.  Maybe they are both part of a bad batch, maybe they sent you back your faulty drive or maybe (but very unlikely) your controller is stuffed and damaging the drives.

As a barely scientific anecdote, I bought a 5  Seagate drives from 2 sources to 2 destinations. 2 of the 5 we're faulty.

Comment: Wow talk about bad luck! Well the controller as such should be fine since i am running 3 x 3TB WD Red on it.

Comment: I've generally found that ordering one disk is reasonably safe, but if you buy 4x at a time, you will almost always have one bad one. I attribute it to packaging for bulk shipping.

Answer (score 0):

The sound you are hearing is the inrush current to the drive spindle getting interrupted after a split-second.  The drive does not appear to be receiving enough power for the motor to spin, so it's constantly retrying.

Usually this kind of situation happens when the power cable is wired wrong or the power supply is faulty.  However, it's extremely unlikely for 3 computers to have this problem.  It's also very unlikely that you would've ordered two bad drives.

The place where you ordered the drive... is it a reputable shop?  Some shady dealers often sell old parts as new or resell known defective merchandise.

But yeah, in summary... that drive just isn't getting enough juice.